# php_value display_errors 0 causes 500 error in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When i uncomment the display_errors line in .htaccess the page throws an internal 500 error.

I have turned every single line on one by one to see where the issue was. But it throws an error only when php_value is active. The thing i don't understand is, this file has worked before. But since today it no longer works.

````
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
#php_value display_errors 0
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "^\.">
require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<Files .htaccess>
require all denied
</Files>
<FilesMatch "database\.php|functions\.php|htmlfunctions\.php|footer\.php|header\.php">
 require all denied
</FilesMatch>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `php_flag display_errors off`

You may need to allow override for your htaccess

please see:
https://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: Im afraid this still throws the same error, i added the Allow Override and replaced php value etc. With php_flag

Comment: Is there anything in your error.log in apache logs folder?

Comment: I have checked the error log, and i found this ```[Mon Jul 29 15:12:14.126389 2019] [core:alert] [pid 26613:tid 139882325538560] [client 92.111.202.155:51132] /home/wopereiswb/domains/bedrijfsveiligheidwopereis.nl/private_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: https://www.bedrijfsveiligheidwopereis.nl/```

Comment: Okay, that would indicate that perhaps mod_php is not enabled. what is currently running on apache?

Comment: I am honestly not sure, i can only access the settings and info for the domain through a directadmin environment. How can i check what's running?

Comment: I have messaged my hosting provider, they have migrated us to a different server that no longer uses mod_php, instead we are on php_fpm now.